# Galois Field of order t

Tags: finite-fields

I am trying to construct a Galois field of order $t$, where $t$ is odd. I can do it when $t$ is an odd prime power. Is there any way to construct a Galois field when $t$ is not a prime power?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the order of a finite field is always a prime power.